# Synchronizing Timer for multiple groups

Tags: jmeter

I need to test the heavy simultaneous load of an API so I have created 10 groups of samplers with 100 threads for each group with looping it twice. Then I tried to get it executed simultaneously by adding a general Synchronizing Timer for the test with a grouping of 100 users but seems that will not execute all 10 groups at once.

Moving Synchronizing Timer to each group will shift some of them even further to be executed in time.

Which approach should I use and what numbers should I put in the Synchronizing Timer to get it to work the way I'm looking for?

PS.
I saw similar questions but answers for them are limited to 2 groups or still are not working the way I wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 10 Thread Groups with 100 threads each and want to release all of them at the same time - you will need to:

1. Add Synchronizing Timer at the same level as Thread Groups, see [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual chapter for more details
2. Set "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" to 1000

As of [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) there is no way to configure Synchronizing Timer to wait for 10 users of each Thread Group, the order will depend on your [ramp-up period settings](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period), first come - first served.

Comment: Any suggestion for ramp-up periods per group like where to start?

Comment: Another question - is it possible to achieve in Jmeter 6k request in 1 sec?